# CCTV connection to OTA feeding multiple TV sets

Tags: tv-antenna

I have security cameras (CCTV) and I'm trying to connect to my TV's that are using an outside antenna.  I've been successful in getting a SV-2G splitter (5/1000 MHz) installed on the OTA feed prior to the Antenna Amplifier.  The other leg of the splitter is where I connected the CCTV feed.  This configuration yields good OTA channels and clarity, but the CCTV is very snowy.  When I installed a Attenuator on the OTA feed (prior to the splitter) it cleaned up the CCTV feed, but have lost 30% of my OTA channels, probably due to the reduced signal input after the Attenuator.  Is there a different type of splitter or Attenuator that I might try to regain the lost TV channels without affecting the quality of the CCTV picture?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should search out "channel modulators" this should help you achieve cctv on whatever channel you have available.